# HTMl/CSS webpage formatting mishap on re-sizing.

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a template for my webpage. I am creating a header and a footer, and have the content in between. But for some reason, I cant get any of it to work. I have been fooling with this for hours and cant find answers.

I have a logo, I am trying to position it inside the  that way it looks clean. But I cant. I wont stay centered on my navigation text! I then notice when I resize my browser, it shifts all my navigation links until they all fit on the screen. How do I fix that?

Upon looking around for the fix, I noticed that I should instead convert all my position: absolute; top: (so many px) left: (so many px); to percent style measurements..no such luck. Once I get this working, I should be pretty much over the hardest part.

here is the css file:

```
//this is not in the div tag rather a test logo outside.
 #logo{
   display: inline;
   float: left;


}
.nav{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 5;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav li{
    display: inline;

}
.nav li img{
    height: 30px;

}
.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 5px 20px 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline;

}

.nav a:visited{
    color: #C0C0C0;
}
.nav a:hover{
   color: black;   
}
```

here is the html

```
    </head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This is a website that offers free information on IT">
    <body>
<!--
 Creating the navigation bar. I used nav as the dic class name with an unordered list
-->
        <a href="index.htm" id="logo"><img src="Images/logo.png"></a>
           <div class="nav">


    <ul>
               <li><img src="Images/logo.png"></li>
               <li><a href="index.htm"> Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
               <li><a href="service.htm">Service</a></li>
               <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
               </ul>
        </div>
         <div class="ad"> 
        <center>
        <a href="contact.htm"><img src="Images/head_pic.jpg"></a>

        <center>
        </div>``
```

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
min-width: (whatever);
```

fixed most of my issues.